# How to get information from and interact with a website from mobile webbrowsers?

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, web-applications

On a mobile web browser, for example, when a user click on the link to an amazon product, I need a way to make a request to a server with product info and receive info about its availability on other online stores, then make an overlay over product image with this info. I need this to be possible while user is browsing and It would be great if it could be independent from browser app (firefox, chrome, etc)

I know chrome for android does not support extensions, firefox does. I do not want to replace browser with a custom app, with a webview or similar.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you control the web site where the link appears?

Comment: No, I dont control the website, take the example: amazon.com.

Comment: In my opinion, the only ways to do it would be via browser extensions, or by injecting code into the web page. If you need to do this for Chrome and it doesn't support extensions, then I'd say you'd have to set up a portal web site and invite users to browse Amazon.com through your portal, where you can add whatever other features you want. However this might violate Amazon's terms of service.

Comment: Oh, I see; an android app with a webview seems to be the only plausible way. Thanks for your answer.